# Create a windows application and consume it as a DLL

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a windows application using c# and want to create a dll for the same so that it can be plugged in to another application as a feature and users can use it.

Can someone guide me how to achieve this feature ?

Comment: Well, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If your windows application has been written in .net, you can reference it from another .net project like it was a dll

Comment: " it can be plugged in to another application" can you elaborate? do you intend to include the DLL into another project and compile it there? or do you intend simply to call this program from another application? the latter one can very simply be achieved by using `Process.Start(...)`.

Comment: There is an application which can have many modules. and all modules are separate window applications which I want to plug to the main application as a dll.

Comment: its kind of some third party dlls for example telerik. You just have to add dll reference of telerik control and after that you can utilize those UI controls provided by telerik.

Comment: Make your windows application consume a library(dll) or a webservice that has the resusable logic. deciding between a webservice or a library depends on what do you want to accomplish. Once both apps consume that element, furute changes would only require either distributing a DLL or publishing a web service.

Comment: If by Module you mean a single control or even a bunch of controls that's one thing, if it's an entire form that's another thing IMHO (though very closely related). Yes, you are probably looking for a windows forms controls library project type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a windows application using c# and want to create a
>   dll for the same so that it can be plugged in to another application
>   as a feature and users can use it.

Well that's wrong totally, why you would want some other app consume a UI application. You mostly want to create a class library and consume that rather. (Or) If you want to have this Winform UI to be used by some other Winform app then you can either create a *User Control* or use *MDI Forms* probably

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. In fact, I've used a dll to encapsulate a few windows forms that was common through several applications of the same client, and it went very well. Admittedly that wasn't an entire application in the dll but I'm pretty sure that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @ZoharPeled am not saying that can't be done ... after all it's a dll too but why would someone include a UI dll rather than using it as re-usable user controls or even include it as MDI forms probably

Comment: @Rahul : I didnt know the exact term. But I think I want to create windows control library.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : Thanks for the comment. I think I am looking for the same what you mentioned. After googling, I believe its called windows control library. am i correct ?

Comment: @Rahul  Sometimes you need entire forms. Though a Form inherits Control, I wouldn't put it as a user control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some existing 'Windows Forms' applications that compile to exes.  You want to still be able to run those exes independently but also run bits of them from a master application (e.g. a launcher application).

You can create a solution with multiple 'Windows Forms' applications and then create a master which references the other projects.  To do this you right click the References section and add a reference.  Then select Solution=>Projects and tick the other executable projects in the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnApp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var f = new WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1();
            f.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnApp2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var f = new WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1();
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

This will result in a bin directory which contains all the executables..

Just because it's possible doesn't mean it's a great idea.  You might want to instead change the 'Output Type' of your existing executables to 'Class Library' (which means they compile to dlls instead of exes) and write seperate launcher applications which only have main and other boot strapping stuff:

- Solution File

  - Original Application without Program.cs and Output Type set to 'Class Library'
  - Launcher which references Original Application and only has Program.cs (output type being Windows Application)